# What am I doing wrong when inserting into a specific data structure?

Tags: c++, insert, containers, sdl-2, stdmap

I am using the SDL2 library to create a game. I am storing loaded **SDL_Textures** into a this **map** container:

```
std::map<const SDL_Texture, std::vector<int[3]>> textures;
```

Where the **key** to the map is the **SDL_Texture** itself. The **value** is a vector of **x,y,z** coordinates to represent all the places to render the texture.

The problem I am having happens when I try to insert an **std::pair** into the structure, like this:

```
textures.insert(
    std::pair<const SDL_Texture, std::vector<int[3]>>( 
       SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(renderer, s), 
       std::vector<int[3]>()
    )
);
```

Where **renderer** is the **SDL_Renderer**, and **s** is a **SDL_Surface**.
The IDE, which is **Visual Studio 2017**, marks it as incorrect:

```
no instance of constructor "std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2>::pair 
[with _ty1=const SDL_Texture, _Ty2=std::vector<int[3],std::allocator<int[3]>>]" 
matches the argument list argument types are: 
(SDL_Texture*, std::vector<int[3],std::allocator<int[3]>>)
```

It clearly doesn't know how to construct the **std::pair**, but I don't know why because I was able to construct one in a **for** loop with no errors:

```
for (std::pair<const SDL_Texture, std::vector<int[3]>> tex : textures) {
}
```

I think it has to do with the uninitialized **std::vector** that I'm inserting as the **value**. Is that the reason? If so, is there a workaround? If not, what could be wrong?

Also, is there a better way to do what I'm trying to do? I'm going for speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the declaration of `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface`:

> ```
> SDL_Texture* SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface(/* arguments omitted for brevity */)
> ```

Pay particular attention to the return type. It's `SDL_Texture*`. That means a *pointer to `SDL_Texture`*.

Next take a look at the key type of your map: `SDL_Texture`. That is different from `SDL_Texture*`. A pointer is (typically) not implicitly convertible to its pointed type.

---

You're not supposed to make copies of `SDL_Texture`. Simplest solution is to store the pointer returned by `SDL_CreateTextureFromSurface`:

```
std::map<SDL_Texture*, std::vector<int[3]>> textures;
```

This will allow you to later release the allocated resources when you no longer need the texture using `SDL_DestroyTexture`.

Comment: How do I destroy the texture inside the map?

Comment: @PlatinumFrog by passing the pointer to `SDL_DestroyTexture`.